# How to use custom aggregation function in pyspark pivot?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The generation syntax for using pivot in pyspark is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create a DataFrame
data = [("Product A", "Region 1", 100),
        ("Product A", "Region 1", 150),
        ("Product A", "Region 2", 200),
        ("Product A", "Region 2", 250),
        ("Product B", "Region 1", 300),
        ("Product B", "Region 1", 350),
        ("Product B", "Region 2", 400),
        ("Product B", "Region 2", 450)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Product", "Region", "SalesAmount"])

# Pivot the DataFrame
pivot_df = df.groupBy("Product").pivot("Region").sum("SalesAmount")

# Show the pivoted DataFrame
pivot_df.show()
```

Say I wanted to do something more esoteric than `sum` that isn't available as an aggregation function then how can that be achieved?

You can just update the above code to use the sum as a custom defined aggregation

Comment: is it possible to use [vectorized UDFs](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html)?

Comment: I tried. It says it isn't implemented yet. Can you post the solution if you can make it work?